# How to set a sign to mark activated users in admin panel

Tags: django

When people register in my website admin gets email notification and admin activates the user. But now, I have many people are registering, that's why I need a field where activated users has a tick or green color. I have no idea how to do that. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AbstractUser to extend default django User module and add an additional property called is_activate.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/